# IONIC 2 radio button inside Virtual scrolling ,multiple option getting selected automatically if I select any one of the option

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

Here is my code for virtual scrolling

```
 <ion-list [virtualScroll]="options" *ngIf="options.length>99" radio-group style="opacity: 0.9;">
    <ion-item *virtualItem="let option">
        <ion-label style="font-size: 12pt" text-wrap>{{ option.optionText }} </ion-label>
        <ion-radio value='{{ option.optionId }}' (ionSelect)="setSelectedOption(option)"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>       
</ion-list>
```

Any help would be appreciated Thanks

Edit-I just found out that this issue has already [been raised](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10726) on GitHub but still if someone could help me with any workaround that would be really very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you're looking for a workaround.

If I look at the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/) for `<ion-radio>`, there is an option called `checked`, like a normal radio button. That would mean that you could do this:

```
<ion-radio value='{{ option.optionId }}' (ionSelect)="setSelectedOption(option)" [checked]="isChecked(option.optionId)"></ion-radio>
```

**ts**

```
options: = [];
selectedOptions: number[] = [];

constructor() {}

setSelectedOption(option: any) {
    let index = this.selectedOptions.indexOf(option.optionId);
    if(index > -1) {
       this.selectedOptions.push(option.optionId);
    } else {
       this.selectedOptions.slice(index, 1);
    }
}

isChecked(id: number): boolean {
    // true if id is in selectedOptions, false if it isn't
    return (this.selectedOptions.indexOf(id) > -1);
}
```

**edit**

Try with normal HTML radio inputs since the ionic ones seem bugged then

```
<form action="">
   <ion-list [virtualScroll]="options" *ngIf="options.length>99" style="opacity: 0.9;">
      <ion-item *virtualItem="let option">
        <ion-label style="font-size: 12pt" text-wrap>{{ option.optionText }} </ion-label>
        <input type="radio" [value]="option.optionId" (click)="setSelectedOption(option) [checked]="isChecked(option.optionId)">
    </ion-item>       
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Ivaro18 but still it's not working. setSelectedOption() method is getting invoked once per selection with the right option object as argument but in the UI I am seeing multiple options getting selected.

Comment: @Abhijeet edited with another workaround without using `<ion-radio>` hopefully this will work